# how do i pass js variable in the where clause rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

```
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :section_id %>     
    <%= f.select :section_id,options_from_collection_for_select(Section.all, :id, :name )%>
</div>


<div class="field">
     <%= f.label :sub_section_id %>
     <div id="sub_section_div"></div>
</div>

<div class="actions"> 
     <%= f.submit %>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

     $("select#sub_section_section_id").change(function(){
          var id_value_string = $(this).val();
          **$('#sub_section_div').html('<%= j f.select :name,options_from_collection_for_select(SubSection.where(:section_id=>1), :id, :name )%>');**          
     });
});
</script>

<% end %>
```

I have two dropdowns `section` and `subSection` in the view page.When i select any section i want to populate its respective sub-section. But the problem is that i want to pass `id_value_string` to the `section_id` in where clause.Please help me out.Thanks.

Comment: Use 4 spaces to indent code, that's a nightmare to read

Comment: why dont you do the same in js.erb file...so you will get the freedom to use ruby in js code...give it a try

Comment: You need to bear in mind that rails and javascript run in completely different environments, and never interact.  Rails runs on the server to generate a text file which is sent back to the browser.  This text file can contain html, javascript etc.  The browser then loads this text file, displays the html and runs the javascript.  So, all interaction between rails and javascript is done via either A) rails rendering out some javascript to run on page load or B) javascript sending a request to the server, ie rails, and doing something with the response it gets back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont work like this, you can't pass JS to Ruby after the page has loaded. I think you'd be better off using AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select#sub_section_section_id").change(function(){
       var id_value_string = $(this).val();

       $.ajax({
           url: "<%= sub_sections_path %>",
           data: {
               section_id: id_value_string
           }
       });     
});
```

You would need to create a new controller/action for this, then in your associated .js view file you can do something like the line you had passing the variable sent via AJAX:

```
$('#sub_section_div').html('<%= j f.select :name,options_from_collection_for_select(SubSection.where(:section_id=>params[:section_id), :id, :name )%>');
```